# Integration question in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $f(z) = A_0 + A_1z + A_2z^2 + \ldots + A_nz^n$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n > 0$.

I need to prove $\int\limits_{|z|=R} \! z^{n-1} |f(z)| dz = 2\pi iA_0 \bar{A_n}R^{2}$.

Now I know when $|z|^2=z\bar z=R^2$ then $\bar z =R^2/z$ ,

I tried $|f(z)|= \sqrt{f(z)\bar{f(z)}}=\sqrt{f(z)\bar f(\bar z))} = \sqrt{f(z)\bar f({R^2\over z })}$

And I said $z^{n-1}\sqrt{\bar f({R^2\over z })} = \sqrt{\bar A_n {R^{2n}z^n\over z^2}+q(z)}$ for some polynomial $q$ since $z^{n-1}=\sqrt{z^{2n-2}}$

I used facts from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204680/complex-analysis-integration-question) post, but I couldn't integrate $\int_{|z|=R} \sqrt{f(z)({\bar A_n {R^{2n}z^n\over z^2}+q(z)})}$.

Need some help.

Comment: The RHS of the claimed formula is of degree $2$ in the coefficients of $f$. I therefore suspect that under the integral sign we should have $|f(z)|^2$.

Comment: My professor just mailed about typo mistake so üt is square, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Christian Blatter mentioned,  there is a square missing. In that case, you have 
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=R}z^{n-1}|f(z)|^2\,dz&=\int_{|z|=R}z^{n-1}\left|\sum_{j=0}^nA_jz^j\right|^2\,dz\\ \ \\
&=\int_{|z|=R}z^{n-1} \sum_{k,j}A_j\overline{A_k}z^j{\bar z}^k \,dz\\ \ \\
&=\sum_{k,j}A_j\overline{A_k}\int_{|z|=R}z^{n-1} z^j{\bar z}^k \,dz\\ \ \\
&=\sum_{k,j}A_j\overline{A_k}\int_0^{2\pi}(Re^{it})^{n-1} (Re^{it})^j(Re^{-it})^k\,iRe^{it} \,dz\\ \ \\
&=i\sum_{k,j}A_j\overline{A_k}R^{n+j+k}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n+j-k)t}\,dz\\ \ \\
&=2\pi i\, A_0\overline{A_n}R^{2n}.
\end{align}
Explanation: the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{igt}\,dt$ is zero whenever $g$ is a nonzero integer, and $2\pi$ when $g=0$. So the only nonzero term in the sum above occurs when $n+j-k=0$, which forces $j=0, n=k$.